# Problem importing background for a little videogame in Python

Tags: python, eclipse, image, pygame, background

I'm just starting to learn python and i follow a video tutorial to code a videogame.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8J8wWxbAdFg&list=PLcX9c3TvvNXueepIGN37deugRCy9KTLk-&index=14

But I already have a problem trying to import a background in jpg. When I run my code it opens a first window saying "I wille open two windows! Continue ?", it gives 3 buttons alternatives "Yes", "No" and "chance". The "no" gives nothing, but when i click "yes" or "chance" a window appears with my jpg file in background but there's a second window (with a red surface with a small kind of 8 bit spaceship a the top of it).
And there's two problems, i don't know why this second window appears, and it's impossible to close these two windows when I click on the cross. I'm obliged to close eclipse (the IDE i work with) and use ctrl+alt+sup

Does anyone can helpto solve this ?

Here's the code i wrote (same than in the video. I think :)

Thanks by advance

```
import pygame
from pickle import TRUE
from pygame.examples.video import backgrounds
pygame.init()


pygame.display.set_caption("Jeu, jeu, jeu")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size=(1080, 720))
background = pygame.image.load("assets/bg.jpg")


running =TRUE

while running:  
    screen.blit(background, (0, -200))
    pygame.display.flip()

for event in pygame.event.get():     
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running= False
        pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please, remove salutations. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: Your answer has some formatting problems (especially typos). Try to improve that to clarify the question. [**TIPS**]: Use `\`` brackets for paths and code fragments. To highlight apps' names or interface, use a **bold** (`**` brackets) or *italic* (`*` brackets) font. To start from a new line use *double space* at the end of the line - the question'll be way more clear than using `Enter` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

> *"and it's impossible to close these two windows when I click on the cross."*

It's a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You have to run the event loop **in** the application loop, instead of **after** the application loop:

```py
running = True
while running:  
    screen.blit(background, (0, -200))
    pygame.display.flip()

# INDENTATION
#-->|    

    for event in pygame.event.get():     
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Rabbid !! I forgot to indent my code in my message but i wrote it like you did in my eclipse.So the problem still exists...